# Simple_Form: Use fieldset/legend for radio buttons / checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, accessibility, simple-form

From an accessibility point of view, it is very important to use `fieldset/legend` combinations for radio buttons and checkboxes:

```
fieldset
  legend What is your sex?

  label for="male" Male
  input type="radio" id="male"

  label for="female" Female
  input type="radio" id="female"
```

This is even true when being inside a `fieldset/legend` pair already, like so:

```
fieldset
  legend Personal information

  label for="name"
  input type="text" id="name"

  fieldset // Yes, this is a fieldset inside a fieldset!
    legend What is your sex?

    label for="male" Male
    input type="radio" id="male"

    label for="female" Female
    input type="radio" id="female"

  label for="email"
  input type="text" id="email"
```

Simple_Form automatically generates `label` elements for these legends, though. Is there an easy way to tell Simple_Form to create `fieldset/legend`s, or do I have to work around this with custom wrappers?

**Update**

For a first work around, I created a custom wrapper like so:

```
config.wrappers :vertical_radio_and_checkboxes, tag: 'fieldset', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-error' do |b|
  b.use :html5
  b.optional :readonly

  b.wrapper tag: 'legend', class: 'col-sm-3 control-label' do |ba|
    ba.use :label # TODO: Doesn't need to be a label tag, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29261556/simple-form-use-fieldset-legend-for-radio-buttons-checkboxes
  end

  b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'col-sm-9' do |ba|
    ba.use :input
    ba.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
    ba.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
  end
end
```

This is okay for the time being, although I didn't find a way to tell Simple_Form not to generate a `label` element for the label (which doesn't point to any ID, which implies that it can't be a correct usage anyway, but it has some important CSS classes added to it, so I didn't want to just abandon it and use `label_text`).

I have added an issue to the Simple_Form-Bootstrap repo: [fieldset/legend should be used for multiple checkboxes/radiobuttons](https://github.com/rafaelfranca/simple_form-bootstrap/issues/50).

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the simple_form generated `<label>` you can use `:label => false`

for example in your `_form.haml`:

```
= f.input :name, :label => false
```

in your form.

Is that what you want to achieve? Not sure that's is all behind your question.

just in case, there might be some useful info [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#user-content-configuration)

Comment: No it's not. Everything should be output as before, but instead of using an additional `label` tag for the name of a radiobutton/checkboxes group, there should be a `legend` output. And everything should be surrounded by a `fieldset`.